# Rails 4: best way to reference table constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables: `posts` and `post_types` (each post is associated with a post_type_id). The post types are pre-defined in seeds.rb like this:

```
PostType.create!([
    {   :id => 1,
            :name => 'Question' },

    {   :id => 2,
            :name => 'Answer' },

    {   :id => 3,
            :name => 'Note' }
])
```

**What is the best way to reference the constants in controllers?**

For example, I currently hard code the post_type_id in my posts#create action:

```
def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(
        :post_type_id => 3,
        :title => post_params[:title],
        :body => post_params[:body])
end
```

Comment: What's the superclass of `PostType`, if any?

Comment: `:post_type_id => PostType.find_by_name('Note').id`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin `PostType < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: @zrl3dx That would be a db call each time it's referenced. Anyway to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it should be cached by Rails (not in development though).

Comment: @zrl3dx good point! I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reference the IDs in your code. There's no guarantee they'll always be the same.

The way I usually handle this is to create a `code` column which is a "slugified" version of the item's name. So, in your case, you'd have a `code` column on `PostType`, and the code for "Question" would be `question`. (To use an example with spaces, "Other post type" would become `other_post_type`.)

Then, in your controller, you can do `PostType.find_by(code: "question")` or, if you want to get fancy, you can implement a helper like `post_type :question` or something like that.

Oh, and if you don't want to do a DB call every time you need to reference the post type id, you can always do something like

```
# app/models/post_type.rb

class PostType < ActiveRecord::Base
  QUESTION = find_by(code: "question")
  ANSWER   = find_by(code: "answer")
  NOTE     = find_by(code: "note")
end
```

Then in the controller you could do `PostType::QUESTION`. Actually, I like that way better than the other things I suggested.

And just to tie the whole thing up:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(
    post_type: PostType::NOTE,
    title: post_params[:title],
    body: post_params[:body]
  )
end
```

Comment: I like the constant approach as well, but isn't the database empty when the constants are defined?

Comment: I believe the presence of those records depends alone on whether you've seeded the database (or created the records by some other mechanism) beforehand.

Comment: Right. I was concerned that in a test environment, they would be created as part of initialization, after the class file is loaded.

Comment: You might be right. I have a gut feeling it would work fine, although I'm not knowledgeable enough to explain why I think that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the idiomatic way is to query for the association and not references ids (bad idea). If you don't have extra logic in your post types, you can define a constant in the post class itself. So, for example, by querying:

```
# Assuming you have post types 'questions' and 'discussions'
# to show one type, you could nest your URLs or pass in a post type /questions/show
@post_type = PostType.find(params[:post_type_id])
@post = Post.new()
```

Otherwise, describing the second method, you could do something like this.

```
class Post
  POST_TYPES = %w[question discussion]
end
```

Comment: What does `POST_TYPES = %w[question discussion]` do? How would I reference that from a controller? Would `%w[question discussion]` map the underlying post_type_id automatically?

Comment: You could, for example, populate a drop down with `Post::POST_TYPES` so you can select a type of post before submitting it.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would consider writing sth like:

```
# Post class

def post_type=(post_type)
  post_type = PostType.find_by(name: post_type) if post_type.is_a? String
  super post_type
end
```

Then you can simply do:

```
@post = current_user.posts.new(
   :post_type => 'Note',
   :title => post_params[:title],
   :body => post_params[:body])
```

Comment: it would do the same as example in question, where id was hardcoded to 3.